# Did Lucifer have any chance?

Tags: satan, omniscience

When Lucifer defied God he must have thought he stood a chance of winning. Did he? And if not how is it he didn't realize that?

Comment: Short answer: Pride, and shortsightedness.

Comment: Other short answer: it's from Paradise Lost, not the bible.

Comment: @affable geek - Are you saying it's not part of christian canon? I would imagine most christians would disagree with that notion.

Comment: Do you mean the cherubim Lucifer or the fallen angel Satan, the devil?

Comment: Indeed, I am saying its not in the canon.  Find it.  I'll even give you two hints: Isaiah 14 & Ezekiel 28 are the two "reference" texts, and they are themselves highly debated. When you read the reference texts, you'll probably be wondering how Christians concocted the whole Lucifer narrative. The answer is John Milton's Paradise Lost, *not* the Bible. Lucifer is more an artifact of the Middle Ages than of the Ancient World.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too speculative for this format. It might make a good blog topic at some point though.

Comment: *Please see [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31389/bishops-have-no-free-will) for the logic behind my response.* Your question should be down voted for "lack of research with some other translations first" - **per Wikis**.  "A) Use a Bible in a language you speak and B) use a dictionary. Either or both of those things would save you from this sort of misunderstanding." - **per Caleb**.  Lucifer isn't the devil or Satan.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that Satan has always defied God, or (and) that he believes his own lies.  The Bible doesn't touch the subject directly.

Comment: Per scripture, the devil did not always defy God. Some time after his creation and before the creation of mankind, Satan rebelled against God.  Before this per Job 38:4-7, the morning stars sang together and all the angels shouted for joy at the creation of the world.

Comment: This whole question about Satan making a choice "before the creation of mankind" requires the existence of Time which does not exist outside our earthly perspective and  is not something humans are able to reference, hence anything related to Time can not be part of our understanding of what choosing based on future outcome is like.

Comment: completely agree.  Some could say, "Why ask such things that are not answerable?  Worry about those that are answerable."  However, Satan must have some sort of chance else he wouldn't battle with him.